# How can I store multiple data in state using spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript

```
     const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
      const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");
      const [file, setFile] = useState<any>([]);
      const [Arr, setArr] = useState<any>([]);
    
      const AddHandle = () => {
        const newData = {
          title: title,
          desc: desc,
        };
        setArr([{ file, ...Arr, newData }]); // I think I made a mistake here
        setDesc("");
        setTitle("");
    
      };
```

I am trying this way but when I add new data, it replaces. How can I store old as well as new data in array? Please, suggest proper solution. Thank you

Comment: if you really need to merge both `Arr` and `file` states together with `newData` into your new `Arr` state, you probably can do something like `setArr([newData, ...file, ...Arr]);`

Answer (score 1):

```
const [state,setState] = useState({
    name:"...",
    age:52
  });

setState(prev=>({...prev,age:26}))
```

setState(prev=>...) this prev parameter provide previous state